# Using truth values between $0$ and $1$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> There are two ways in which we can use all real numbers between $0$
>   and $1$ to represent Boolean expressions that satisfy De Morgan's
>   Laws. What are they?

I have found the first way. For propositions $p, q \in [0, 1]$, define $p \wedge q = \text{min}(p, q)$ and $p \vee q = \text{max}(p, q)$, and define $\neg p = 1 - p$.

These satisfy De Morgan's Laws.

I can't find the second one. Can someone please help me? I've seen it before, and I remember that it only used algebra (multiplication, addition, subtraction). They didn't have any special functions (like max/min). Can someone please help me recall them?

Comment: Idea: Take the one you have, but round after applying $\min$ and $\max$: $\land$ is rounded down (of the result isn't $1$ it's set to $0$) and $\lor$ is rounded up (if the result isn't $0$, set it to $1$). Haven't checked the laws.

Comment: there's one way to do it with just algebra. i remember seeing it. i am trying to remember that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define

$ p ∧ q := p \times q $

$ ¬p := 1 - p $

then you can define disjunction *to make* the DeMorgan laws hold, and you get

$ p ∨ q := 1 - ( (1 - p) \times (1 - q) ) $